# Hibernate Criterion: wrap object Criterion in Exists

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Currently we have a difficult logic for generate Criterion object. And we need to wrap the finally generated criterion in "exists" operator. For example, the sql code generated of Citerion object:

```
Select tbl1.name from tbl1
```

and in result we want to have in generated Criterion object

```
exists (Select tbl1.name from tbl1)
```

Maybe, someone have any ideas. I wathced on DetachedCriteria, but it not applicable in current issue

Comment: It' s not applicable in current context